# Jasmine Marbles: testing custom RXJS Operator for handling HTTP

Tags: angular, rxjs, jestjs, jasmine-marbles

I wrote this function here for an incremental Http retry, but I am a bit confused about how to test it:

```
export const incrementalHttpRetry = (delayArg: number = 500, numberOfRetries: number = 5): OperatorFunction<any, any> => {
  return retryWhen(errors => {
    let delayTime = delayArg;
    return errors.pipe(
      flatMap((error: any) => {
        delayTime = delayTime * 2;
        return of(error.status).pipe(delay(delayTime));
      }),
      take(numberOfRetries)
    );
  });
};
```

I assume I need to do something like this, but I am not sure where to go from there, it seems a needs to be a mocked Http-call rather than an Error-instance

```
describe('incrementalHttpRetry', () => {
  it('only errors => should return the errors but delayed', () => {
    const values = { a: new Error('some error')};
    const source = cold('-a-a-a-|', values);
    const result = source.pipe(incrementalHttpRetry(1, 5));
    expect(result).toBeObservable(source);
  });
});
```

But what I want to test is that one error (given a handler that always fails), will result in a stream of 5 errors.